# c++ vector initialization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, initialization, c++11

I have been using the following vector initialization with values in Code::Blocks and MingW compiler:

```
vector<int> v0 {1,2,3,4};
```

After that I had to move the code to a visual studio project (c++) and I tried to build. I got the following error:
*local function definitions are illegal*

Visual Studio compiler does not support this kind of initialization?
How do I need to change the code to make it compatible?
I want to initialize vector and fill it with values at the same time, just like an array.

Comment: This syntax is new to C++11, and not yet supported in Visual C++.

Comment: This syntax is now supported in VS 2013. Source: [What's New for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh409293.aspx)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Visual C++ does not yet support initializer lists.

The closest you can get to this syntax is to use an array to hold the initializer then use  the range constructor:

```
std::array<int, 4> v0_init = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector<int> v0(v0_init.begin(), v0_init.end());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do nearly that in VS2013

```
vector<int> v0{ { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
```

Full example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{    
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> v0{ { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
    for (auto& v : v0){
        cout << " " << v;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is `boost::assign`:

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>


using namespace boost::assign;
vector<int> v;
v += 1,2,3,4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have defined a macro :

```
#define init_vector(type, name, ...)\
    const type _init_vector_##name[] { __VA_ARGS__ };\
    vector<type> name(_init_vector_##name, _init_vector_##name + _countof(_init_vector_##name))
```

and use like this :

```
init_vector(string, spell, "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" );

for(auto &a : spell)
  std::cout<< a <<" ";
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're using `Visual Studio 2015`, the way to initialize a `vector` using a `list` is:

```
vector<int> v = {3, (1,2,3)};
```

So, the first parameter `(3)` specifies size and the list is the second parameter.

Comment: I tried your way but, all elements has the last value.

Comment: That's not a list. `(1,2,3)` is just an expression using the comma operator and equivalent to `3`.