# C++ std::vector, static initialisation

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am working on a project that includes a member variable, in the class definition:

```
    static std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < UINT16 > > >  m_vectors;
```

This looks like a 3 dimensional array of unsigned 16 bit integers.

Presently the initialisation for this is done by creating multiple UINT16 arrays and then transferring these into m_vectors with a memcpy.

I am looking for a way of performing this initialisation in the cpp file, something like:

```
    std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < UINT16 > > > cname::m_vectors = 
    {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12};
```

The data is just for illustration purposes, is this possible?

Edit:  Using Qt I tried the following:

```
    std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < int > > > test{{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}}};
```

Build and ran in the debugger this worked perfectly, I will email this test to myself and test on the development system tomorrow, I am using MSVC 2010 on the development system.

Edit.2 I've just tried the same logic on my development system, this is running Windows 7 [6.1.7601] and Microsoft Visual Studio [10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel]  with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 [01018-532-2002181-70881]

In my class header I have:

```
    static std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < UINT16 > > > m_vectors;
```

In my cpp file I have:

```
    std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < UINT16 > > > cname:m_vectors{{{
    0x01,0x02,0x03}}};
```

The data is just an example but the format is the same.  When I compile I get:

```
    error C2470: 'cname:m_vectors' : looks like a function definition,  but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
```

This same logic which is almost the same as the first Edit which was on my MacBook Pro running iOS and Qt 5.11 compiles and works.

I'm now thinking this is more of an issue with MSVC 2010 and not the syntax.

Comment: A list of lists of lists of numbers is *not* a 3D array. The latter is rectangular. If you are refactoring stuff anyway, sounds like a good chance to fix the data structure; chances are that also solves a handful of other problems.

Comment: @BaummitAugen while I do agree with you, I think, the initialization question can be answered on it's own merit.

Comment: Latest C++? Or is this gonna be constrained to something like [tag:c++03]?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, the mix up of 3d is probably just my misunderstanding, it is referenced using [][][].

Comment: I wonder who voted to close as 'unclear what you are asking' - what exactly is unclear here? To me the question is pretty clear.

Comment: @SergeyA Of course it can, as you aptly demonstrated. I just wanted to point out that the wrong question is asked to begin with, probably.

Comment: @SPlatten You can make a proper ndarray class that supports just that, if this is supposed to be an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it is possible.

```
static std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<UINT16>>> m_vectors{
                  {
                    {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3}
                  },
                  {
                    {3, 5, 6}, {3, 5, 6}
                  }
};
```

This is using list initialization of `std::vector` - see more at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector (overload 8)

Comment: I'm now getting an error C2470: ' cname::m_vectors': looks like a function, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body

Comment: @SPlatten please provide the full except of the code, also, what is your C++ version?

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575776/c-vector-initialization  which would explain my current issues.